# How to get noise data from ESP32

Tags: c, arduino, esp32

I am using M5StickC, trying to use the microphone for sensing noise. I am not familiar with Arduino. I was able to connect the device to wifi. I have been looking at examples and got this :

```
bool InitI2SMicroPhone()
{
    esp_err_t err = ESP_OK;
    i2s_config_t i2s_config = {
        .mode = (i2s_mode_t)(I2S_MODE_MASTER | I2S_MODE_RX | I2S_MODE_PDM),
        .sample_rate = 44100,
        .bits_per_sample = I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_16BIT, // is fixed at 12bit, stereo, MSB
        .channel_format = I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_ALL_RIGHT,
        .communication_format = I2S_COMM_FORMAT_I2S,
        .intr_alloc_flags = ESP_INTR_FLAG_LEVEL1,
        .dma_buf_count = 2,
        .dma_buf_len = 128,
    };

    i2s_pin_config_t pin_config;
    pin_config.bck_io_num = I2S_PIN_NO_CHANGE;
    pin_config.ws_io_num = PIN_CLK;
    pin_config.data_out_num = I2S_PIN_NO_CHANGE;
    pin_config.data_in_num = PIN_DATA;
    

    err += i2s_driver_install(I2S_NUM_0, &i2s_config, 0, NULL);
    err += i2s_set_pin(I2S_NUM_0, &pin_config);
    err += i2s_set_clk(I2S_NUM_0, 44100, I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_16BIT, I2S_CHANNEL_MONO);
    //i2s_set_clk(0)

    if (err != ESP_OK)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

However, I am not sure how to get amplitude data. I want to get noise info and send it over wifi. I do not see this function in Loop. How can I extract the needed info in the Loop function?

Comment: You're using the Espressif ESP-IDF library, not the Arduino library from what it looks like. Which ever you choose, you then need to configure your IDE for that environment. I'm not sure what the nature of the question is. If your mic is an I2C device, then the documentation for that device should indicate what commands are available for obtaining specific information you need. You would then issue these commands using the i2c functions. If you want use the Arduino tools, then you want to use the Arduino [M5StickC](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/m5stickc/) library.

Comment: yes, I have installed M5StickC library in Arduino IDE, and I am looking at example codes of M5StickC. I am confused about how to get the data, this function, I guess does the setup. But it returns nothing. I am trying to figure out how can I put a piece of code in Loop to get microphone data in regularly and print it.

Comment: I see. The library does seem to rely on direct ESP-IDF library calls. Did you try building and running one of the basic example programs from the library? For example, the basic/microphone program?

Comment: yes, the factory code comes with a screen to show microphone data. I also tried a code to show the microphone data as a wave. I got this particular piece of code from these examples.